# Upload update with different identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I've wrote a project in **Swift** and uploaded it to app store.
but then I wanted to support iPhone 4 and **iOS 7** so I started a new project on **Objective-C** but with different bundle id, I tried to rename it but the **.xcodeproj** file got deleted.
So how can I upload the new project with it's new identifier, written in Objective c, to the same app in **itunesconnect**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved this by creating new project, because every other solution i searched including changing the bundle id, didn't work for me

Answer (score 3):

The bundle identifier must be same for this purpose. Why dont you just change bundle identifier of the new project to the previous one and upload?

Comment: I tried but as i said it made my xcdoeproj be deleted

Comment: You said you tried with a different bundle id. Try it with same bundle id as a new version to current application.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to change the bundle identifier to upload an update, even if you are supporting older iPhone models. But if you have strong reason to change the bundle identifier and want to upload it as a new application, you can still do it. The problem is you have to go through the entire app approval process from the beginning, which will take more time than updating an existing application.

Coming to your original question, you can still create new Xcode project and move all the Objective-C files and give a new bundle identifier and upload it as new application. cannot you?